# Access Denied When Creating a new File Using Filestream - Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I am trying to create an empty PDF file in Xamarin.IOS using Filestream. When I try to create the Filestream using the following code:
`FileStream fs = new FileStream("InvestmentAgreemen.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);`

I get the following error: "Access to the path "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/05AA1616-B66B-483D-8BA1-80A2B1AEC973/NewEPA.app/InvestmentAgreemen.pdf" is denied."

It worked fine when running on the iPad simulator, but as soon as I moved it to a real device I got this permissions error. Additionally, I have to use a filestream to create the empty PDF because I am also using Syncfusion's PDF tools for xamarin.IOS which require the use of Filestream for saving.
I also tried creating a FileIOPermission object granting AllAccess to AllFiles but I got a system not allowed error.
How can I resolve this permissions error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to create a file in the root of your application's bundle, which is read-only.  I'm surprised that this didn't fail on the simulator also.

To create a file at runtime, you need to specify a [user writable path](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/)

```
var documents =
 Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments); 
var filename = Path.Combine (documents, "InvestmentAgreemen.pdf");
```

Comment: thanks, that worked out perfectly! I feel like that should have been obvious to me, but the fact that it worked on the simulator threw me off.

Comment: Most sandbox restrictions are *not* enforced on the iOS simulator, including file access.

Comment: It failed for me in simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Create your `pdf` within a writable directory of your application instead of the root directory of the bundle:

```
using (var docPath = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrl(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.All, null, true, out var nsError))
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(docPath.Path, "InvestmentAgreemen.pdf"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    // do something with the file stream
}
```

Comment: that did the trick. I ended up moving it to the documents folder and everything worked fine

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample which creates and saves the PDF document in Xamarin.IOS platform. Which can be downloaded from the below location:
http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/184238/ze/PDFSave1731207096

Please try the sample and let me know whether the issue is fixed.

Regards,
Surya Kumar